# Creating select in BeanEditForm from Hibernate and Tapestry IOC

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

How can I make a select box in BeanEditForm for some key that is not showing
in BeanEditForm for example I have a table:

```
Person:

IDPerson
PersonName
```

and table

```
Contact:

IDContact
IDPerson
ContactName
```

and I want to create a BeanEditForm with allows me to choose
a person from list when adding a contact in tapestry 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following

```
<t:beaneditor t:id="contact" add="person" object="contact">
    <p:person>
        <t:select .../>
    </p:person>
</t:beaneditor>
```

It should work, but I'm typing that from top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a beaneditform with 'add' and a block parameter, as suggested by Michal Gruca, or you can use the beaneditor directly. A `<t:beaneditform />` is just a `<t:beaneditor />` inside a `<t:form />`

eg:

```
<t:form t:id="contactForm">
    <t:errors/>
    <t:beaneditor object="contact" include="firstName,lastName" />
    <t:label for="person" /><t:select t:id="person" value="contact.person" model="..." />
    <t:beaneditor object="contact" include="height,age" />
    <input type="submit" value="message:submit-label" />
</t:form>
```